# Vertx : Keep serve alive after closing PDF file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, vert.x

I use Vertx and Jasper Reports, I could create successfully my reports but when I close PDF file Server stop running. I'de like to let my server continue running.

Here is my code:

```
 public void start(Future<Void> startFuture){
    String fileJSON = "{name : 'Stackoverflow', start: '15-06-2014', end: '02-09-2018'}";
    String file =  "/Test1";
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
       router.route(file).handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        response.setChunked(true);            
        InputStream iostream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileJSON.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                try{                                  
                    JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(iostream);
                    Map parametersMap = new HashMap();  
                    String report = "C:\\PathToreport\\report2.jrxml";
                    JasperReport Jasp = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
                    JasperPrint JASP_PRINT = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Jasp,parametersMap,ds);
                    JasperViewer.viewReport(JASP_PRINT);
                    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JASP_PRINT, "C:\\Users\\path\\report4.pdf");                             
                    }
                catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
        routingContext.vertx().setTimer(1000, tid ->  routingContext.response().end());
    });
    vertx.createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(router::accept)
            .listen(8089, "localhost", res -> {

                if (res.succeeded()){

                    startFuture.complete();    
                }
                else
                    startFuture.fail(res.cause());
            });


}
```

Here is the stack :

```
vr. 07, 2016 9:25:04 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker AVERTISSEMENT: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 2407 ms, time limit is 2000 avr. 07, 2016 9:25:05 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker AVERTISSEMENT: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 3407 ms, time limit is 2000 avr. 07, 2016 9:25:06 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker AVERTISSEMENT: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 4407 ms, time limit is 2000 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 27 seconds)
```

Comment: Please post stack trace of the error.

Comment: I added some code to keep it alive by using some code :response.putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        response.write(new JsonObject("{\"error\": false, \"file\":\"report44\"}").encodePrettily());
                        response.end();
but it gives me : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been written.

Comment: @zackzulg [edit] your question with this stacktrace do not pass it as comment.

Comment: @PetterFriberg the problem wasn't in semantic of code, I had to add false arg to my viewReport. It works now.

Comment: @zackzulg, why do you call JasperViewer.viewReport(JASP_PRINT, false);?

Comment: Just remove the line....

Comment: @PetterFriberg I use it to display my report and keep server running after closing my PDF, the second argument is isExitOnClose, so if you allow it, so task done but if you deny it your work continue, as I see it let server continue his work. Correct me if my idea is wrong.
Regards.

Comment: Yeah its seems really strange that you generate a pdf then launch a JasperViewer.viewReport (this does not show the pdf, but the jasper report) on your server, it supposed to be used in Swing (installed applications) to show a report in application. I guess your question is more unclear then problem can no longer be reproduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to add false argument to viewReport

JasperViewer.viewReport(JASP_PRINT, false);